# Click event defined in another function but when triggered in view it enters a loop on Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a button on the header file that opens a popup and I'm using Backbone to generate the views. Problem is that in one of the views I have a button that I want it to have the exact same event but when it's triggered it enters an infinite loop and I can't really understando why...

Here's the click event for the header button:

```
$(function() {
.....
$dnaBtn.on('click', function() {
    var $overlay = $('div.overlay#dnaForm'),
        $activePane = $('div.pane.active', $lightbox),
        $eq = $activePane.index(),
        $shape = $('.shape img').eq(0),
        $shapeActive = $('.shape .active'),
        $torso = $('.torso .shape img').eq(0),
        $torsoActive = $('.torso .shape .active');
        console.log('d');
    $lightbox.fadeIn(300, 'easeInOutCubic', function() {
        var $ticks = $('div.tick', $pane.first()),
            $count = 0;
.....
```

The view

```
var EndTourView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#ism-tour",
    events:{
        "click a.dna-btn":"showsmth"
    },
    initialize:function(){
        this.$el.html('');
        this.render();
    },
    render:function(){
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#end-tour-template").html());

        this.$el.html(template());

        return this;            
    },
    showsmth:function(){

        var $lightbox = $('div.lightbox'),
        $padding = $('div.overlay#dnaForm div.padding', $lightbox),
        $animator = $('div.animator', $padding),
        $pane = $('div.pane', $animator);
        console.log('dddd')
        $(".dna-btn").click();
    }


});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function showsmth when you click .dna-btn and then within showmsth you are clicking .dna-btn. This will invoke the function again and it will keep repeating in an infinite loop.

If they are two different .dna-btn's the `$(".dna-btn").click();` calls the click event on every instance of .dna-btn. If that is the case, you'll have to call them something different.

Comment: That's so obvious ... Renamed the backbone event trigger and it's working now. Thanks a lot